# Marching Voxel FEA Mesh

Tags: finite-element-method, meshing

I'm working on an FEA model and my mesher uses a "Marching Voxel method" I'm wondering what the relationship is between mesh size and computation time is? I.e. if I half the mesh size (1mm to 0.5mm) is the computation time for the tighter resolution doubled? quadrupled? eight times longer?

Comment: A first guess from other packages (Poenics) would be doubled, but your best option is to take an example model and run, double the mesh and see not only the time taken but any accuracy change.

Comment: marching voxels is a method of discretizing surfaces.  What kind of mesh are you generating?  What is the mesher? In any case First thing to do is look at the actual trend in element count with mesh size.